# Static variable in C not "working"

Tags: c, variables, static

I had an issue today while I was coding a function which uses a `static char*` in C.
Let me explain : My function finds a `'\n'` in a buffer that we send to her, and if there is any text behind the `'\n'`, it must stock this text into the static variable called `rest`. The fact is that it stocks it, but the content of `rest` is not preserved between two calls of the function. And I don't understand why this is happening despite it being declared as a static variable.

Here is my function so far :
(`return (1)` means the function didn't find either the `\n` and the `\0`, `return (0)` means the function found the `\n`, (`return -1`) means the function found the `EOF`)

```
static int  end_line(char *buf, char **line)
{
    static char *rest;
    char        *tmp;

    rest = NULL;
    tmp = ft_strnew(ft_strlen(buf));
    tmp = buf;
    printf("REST BEGINNING : %s\n", rest);
    if (rest != NULL)
    {
        tmp = ft_strnew(ft_strlen(rest) + ft_strlen(buf));
        tmp = ft_strcat(rest, buf);
    }
    if (!ft_strchr(tmp, '\n') && ft_strchr(tmp, '\0') == NULL)
    {
        rest = tmp;
        return (1);
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putstr("OK\n");
        *line = ft_strsub(tmp, 0, (ft_strlen(tmp) - ft_strlen(ft_strchr(tmp, '\n'))));
        rest = ft_strchr(tmp, '\n') + 1;
        if (ft_strlen(ft_strchr(tmp, '\0')) == 0)
            return (-1);
        return (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where else is `test_static` used apart from its declaration?

Comment: Sorry test_static is a test I forgot to delete before posting ^^
And what is the problem initializing rest to NULL?

Comment: Should really give more minimal code example, write question more concisely.

Comment: Besides there is a problem.

Comment: The problem is that is no initialisation, but an assignment.

Comment: What do you mean by an assignement...? Is that because NULL is a state and isn't a value?

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9

Answer (score 3):

One major problem is that each time the function is called you *reassign* `NULL` to `rest`, instead of initially just initialize `rest`.

Just remove the assignment, `static` local variables are zero-initialized by default (i.e. pointers will be `NULL`).

If you do wish to explicitly initialize it, do so in the declaration. e.g.:

```
static char *rest = NULL;
```

Comment: But a static variable is only initialized once, right? When I test without initializing it, or initializing it into the declaration, the program makes a segfault...

Comment: @S_Mindcore Then you need to figure out why. One reason might be that you assign `rest` to `buf` (indirectly anyway). Will the life-time of `buf` (or rather, the first argument you initially pass to the function) outlive the use of `rest`? You should also figure out a way to reset `rest`. There are actually to many unknowns in the code you show, what are the `ft_*` functions, and what do they do? And you did try to run in a debugger to catch the crash in action?

Comment: I'll try to reset rest and find out if the lifetime of buf impacts on rest, thanks !
All the ft_* functions are exactly the same as the ones from the libc, I wrote them myself but they do the same work, with no doubt. (except strnew, it creates a new string initialized to NULL with a size in parameter)
Didn't think about running in a debugger...